# -h not working for 'ls' command in Sun SPARC

Tags: sun, sparc, ls, solaris

I was trying this command for listing files in human readable form:

```
$ ls -lh                                                                                                                                         
ls: illegal option -- h
usage: ls -1RaAdCxmnlogrtucpFbqisfL [files]
```

Is there a way to enable it?

I am using Sun SPARC:

```
$ uname -a                                                                                                                                       
SunOS www 5.8 Generic_108528-16 sun4u sparc SUNW,UltraAX-i2
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably not whilst still using Solaris 8, you'll probably need to upgrade to get that functionality.

Answer (score 3):

The GNU version of `ls` can be found in the `coreutils` package at [Sun Freeware](http://sunfreeware.com/programlistsparc8.html#coreutils).

Comment: +1, the dependency list is quite short too.